# Cryptic polygon issue leading to incorrect rasterization

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I have a number of spatial polygons that I am rasterizing, using the `sf` and `raster` packages. It has worked out great, except for this one case, where I have run out of ideas as to how to fix the problem:

I have a polygon as a simple feature polygon, and a raster template. Both have been transformed to an equal area Behrmann projection. There was a geometry validity issue with the polygon, which I fixed with `st_make_valid` from the `lwgeom` package.

```
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)
library(raster)

spfile <- 'sp.rds'
rasterfile <- 'rasterTemplate_150km.tif'

sp <- readRDS(spfile)
rasterTemplate <- raster(rasterfile)

# are there any geometry validity issues? yes!
st_is_valid(sp)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In evalq((function (..., call. = TRUE, immediate. = FALSE, noBreaks. = FALSE,  :
  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 9947244.3466675151 1450099.5373749144


sp2 <- st_make_valid(sp)

st_is_valid(sp2)
[1] TRUE

plot(sp2, col='blue')
```

[image]
Visually, the polygon looks good.

Now I rasterize it (I need to convert to SpatialPolygon for compatibility with raster):

```
sp3 <- as(sp2, 'Spatial')

cover <- rasterize(sp3, rasterTemplate, getCover=TRUE)

plot(cover, box=F, axes=F)
```

[image]

The problem is that there is a bar going through Australia.

Does this mean that there is still a geometry validity issue with that polygon that is not detected by `st_is_valid`? If so, that makes this type of issue hard to work with, as it is not easily detected, except visually...

Going back, I can confirm that the rasterization problem happens with `as(sp, 'Spatial)`, so `st_make_valid` doesn't create this problem.

How can I fix this problem?

UPDATES

A suggestion below was made to use `st_cast`. I tried `sp4 <- as(st_cast(sp, "POLYGON"), 'Spatial')`. The same rasterization problem remains.

I also tried buffering by 0 with `sp5 <- as(st_buffer(sp, dist = 0), 'Spatial')`, but this also does not solve the problem.

The polygon can be downloaded as a .rds file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn4rbl04ld2uqy6/sp.rds?dl=1). 
The raster can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq681g19abvdmqy/rasterTemplate_150km.tif?dl=1).

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is, but perhaps try doing `sp3 <- st_cast("POLYGON") <- st_make_valid()`, and see what that produces from the raster? My experience with `st_make_valid` is that it can produce some pretty wacky output in its effort to pass `st_is_valid` and I couldn't find good documentation on how it works. But at least casting to `POLYGON` might prevent boundaries from being mixed across polygons? Compare the output of `plot(st_cast(sp, "POLYGON")[1])` to `plot(st_cast(st_make_valid(sp), "POLYGON")[1])`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @CalumYou! Following your suggestion, I did `sp3 <- st_cast(sp2, "POLYGON")`, `sp4 <- as(sp3, 'Spatial')` and `cover <- rasterize(sp4, rasterTemplate, getCover=TRUE)`, but I get the same result with the bar through Australia.

Comment: Hmm. Does not returning `TRUE` for `st_is_valid` prevent `rasterize` or `as('Spatial')` working? What if you use the "trick" of `st_buffer(sp, 0.0)` instead of `st_make_valid`? What does the plot of `sp3` look like?

Comment: @CalumYou, everything actually runs with `sp`, despite the validity issue. In other words, the rasterization problem crops up no matter what, so far. `sp3` looks identical to the plot I have above of sp2. I'm a bit confused why the polygon looks fine when plotted, yet leads to these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fasterize function from [fasterize](https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/fasterize) package apparently does not cause the same error. Fasterize will also be incorporated into the [stars](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars) package [(see this issue)](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/2), which should be on CRAN soon.

There is also no need to st_cast or st_make_valid.

```
library(sf)
library(fasterize)

df <- readRDS('sp.rds') %>% st_sf(field = 1)
template <- raster('rasterTemplate_150km.tif')
r <- fasterize(df, template, field = 'field')
plot(r)
```

[image]